# Running PHP on my machine locally?

Tags: php

I download xampp 1.7.7 and it has PHP and MySQL. I bought a book named *HeadFirst PHP MySQL*. My problem is that I can't run the examples from the book.

The example files consist of 2 files: one HTML, and one PHP file. The example is like this you fill the form from HTML file then send it to a web server then the php will handle the HTML file then return it to you.

When I filled the form then I click the submit button, it didn't return what it was supposed to return. What it returns is the actual PHP code.

Do I need to transfer all the files from the book to a webhost so that I cant try the examples I said? How can I run it locally?

UPDATE!!
I tried what anselm said now it says OBJECT not found... url not found then the 404 error.

Comment: I greatly prefer WAMP which is very easy to get started with: http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Comment: Your xampp stat... then You put two files in htdocs folder.. Run the file http://localhost/file_name.html

Comment: when I click the submit button it returns this *file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/index.php*

Comment: try http://localhost/index.php to access your form

Comment: anselm - it works like that but the problem is if I accesss the html file it didnt return the php file

Comment: Don't try just running their samples. Read the start of the book and create a PHP page. Make one that says, "Hello World!" Do a bit more hand-coding ... THEN work the samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP code isn't being parsed by PHP.  Either the Apache config is wrong (unlikely since you installed XAMPP, but you can check by following the steps at http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.apache2.php), or your files aren't really named `.php`.

In Windows, make sure you have file extension viewing turned on, and ensure the file extensions really are `.php`.

Comment: +1  To turn file extension viewing on as Brad suggests, access any Windows Explorer window and choose Tools > Folder Options, View tab, remove the checkbox next to "Hide extensions for known file types"

Comment: when I try .php file on browser it works like <?php echo 'hello';?>

Comment: See @anselm's post.  You need to load your files through your server, rather than just opening them directly.

Comment: @user1364686, Your file is in the wrong place.  Put it in the doc root.

Comment: i put them in the htdoc is that the root directory?

Answer (score 5):

Ensure that you're accessing the html file through `http://localhost/file.html` instead of `c:\etc etc.html`

Comment: anselm I tried what you said now it says OBJECT NOT found..url not found then the 404 error.

Comment: Ensure that both `.html` and `.php` file are in htdocs. ensure the `action="index.php"` value of the form points correctly

Comment: Assuming your files are called `index.html` and `index.php`. try accessing the files using `http://localhost/index.html` and `http://localhost/index.php` if both of them exist try checking the form code.

Answer (score 3):

if you are developing on windows i really recommend using wamp it really easy to use and include the main stuck which is php, mysql, apache it really easy to install and automatically configures everything you then can find www folder in wamp folder on your c drive where you have to drop you php files

http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Answer (score -2):

In your XAMPP Control Panel, make sure that Apache started.

Comment: Apache is started, or he wouldn't be getting anything.